# Sheet not found via codename

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running across and error that appears sporadically.  Essentially, a master .xlsm file is used by multiple people to populate data for aggregation.  I then use another .xlsm file with macros to pull the data and aggregate it into a single source file.

The code generally works quite well, with one exception:

```
'define range based on count'
Set rngItemRange = SourceWb.Sheets("Quality").Range(Cells(3, i), Cells((intItemCount + 2), i))

'write concatenated range'
targetwb.Sheets("Raw Data").Cells(pintDest_row, pintCol).Value = concatRange(rngItemRange)
```

It cannot find the tab "Quality" on some work books (but not all).  Okay, maybe someone renamed the tab?  checked that, thats not true.  One thing that works as a work around: on the open source workbook, when debug throws an error, if i manually click the quality tab, then resume the macro, it will continue.

I also said, okay, well maybe there's some weird character recognition issue, so I started to refer to the sheet by the codename as shown in the vba editor.  I experience the same behaviors.

This affects maybe 50% of the workbooks, and I cant find any root cause.  I have similar code elsewhere, for different sheets, but this is the only one where i define a range to pass into a function using the "set" command.  Again, this only happens sometimes on some workbooks, and i can continue to execute when i manually click on the tab i'm pulling data from.

I'll also add, there is only one workbook open with this sheet name, at any given time, so i dont think it's choking trying to figure which sheet is relevant.  Plus sourceWb is a set variable.

Does someone have any clue whats going on? anything to try? solutions? help!
(Forgive any typos, I'm working on a broken thumb right now.)

Comment: **ALL** range objects, these include the `Cells()` inside the `Range` needs to have their parent set, otherwise it is looking for the active sheet.  `Set rngItemRange = SourceWb.Sheets("Quality").Range(SourceWb.Sheets("Quality").Cells(3, i), SourceWb.Sheets("Quality").Cells((intItemCount + 2), i)`

Comment: You can go by `With SourceWb.Sheets("Quality") _ Set rngItemRange = .Range(.Cells(3, i), .Cells((intItemCount + 2), i)) _ End With`

Comment: you guys are beautiful.  Thank you!  ive been trying like hell to figure out whats going on.  Also, my follow on was "is there a more elegant way to type it..." the with makes sense.